# How to send down a List<T> with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

So here's my DTO, when I debug I CLEARLY see the Roles list populated... but in the endpoint /RestApi/myroute?format=json (or any format) there's nothing there.  Tried changing List to a dto object, same deal.

```
    public class PageItemDto {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PageId { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Ordinal { get; set; } = 0.0f;
    public string RolesJson { get; set; }

    public List<string> Roles = new List<string>();
}
```

If I then do

```
pageItem.RolesJson = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(pageItem.Roles);
```

The RolesJson property shows what should be in the list...

What am I missing here, I SWEAR I've sent nested objects a billion times.

Comment: Can you clearly show your setup as Request DTO, Response DTO and your service?  When returning your Response DTO from your service, you don't need to use JsonSerializer, just return your List<string> and will return JSON string array. Hard to tell what the issue is from what you have provided, the more info the better.

Comment: Well I suppose that's my problem... I only used the JsonSerializer as a sanity check (and so I could actually continue working) https://gist.github.com/sitefinitysteve/b1c5b37d50167cc52c7b1d6ca618b98e

It SHOULD be returning the List<string> but isn't... it's CLEARLY in the debugger

Comment: Even more confusing I can make a nested object off of PageItemDto, and THAT has a List<string> and it properly comes down... its like root level object in the array just don't deliver the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only **public properties** are serialized by default, so your DTO should be changed to:

```cs
public class PageItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PageId { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Ordinal { get; set; } = 0.0f;
    public string RolesJson { get; set; }

    public List<string> Roles { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: I checked public first, but OH GOD...  I didn't have the Getter\Setter... jeez. It's been like a couple hours of that (not) staring me right in the face. I thought I was going insane.